# RailsAdmin Gem - Customize multi-select dropdown with conditional values only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin, rails-administrate

We have implemented `gem 'rails_admin', '~> 1.4.3'` in our application.
The issue we are facing here is in customizing the output values in the multi-select dropdown in rails admin.

For example: `Student` has many `Teachers`. So while creating a `Student` record we will have a multi-select dropdown of `Teachers`. Here we only want those `Teachers` who are in `active` state, not all the teachers.

To achieve the same, we have implemented something like below in the `student_admin.rb` file.

```
create do
  field :name do
    required true
  end

  field :teachers do
    visible do
      Teacher.where(state: 'active')
    end
  end
end
```

The above code neither gives any error nor filters the only active teachers.

Can someone help to get the expected result here.
Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
edit do
  field :name do
    required true
  end

  field :teachers do
    associated_collection_scope do
      proc { |scope| scope.where(state: 'active') }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for response - I have added above code block but still it doesn't filter out teachers as per the `where` condition.

Comment: Can you try to change the name of the block from create to edit?

Comment: Did it - still same - nothing changes - all active and inactive teachers are displayed in dropdown.

Comment: Do you have more than one config for this model? Can you update your answer with the entire block of code?